# Visibility guarantees of atomic variables

Tags: java, visibility, atomic, volatile

Having read lots about volatile, atomic and visibility, one question remains. Following works across threads, "a" is visible all the time, when "b" is updated/read:

```
int a;
volatile int b;
a = 1; b = 1;
...
// different thread
if (b == 1) // do something with a, which is 1 now
```

Does the same hold true with atomic variables, which are separate objects, will the following work?

```
int a;
AtomicInteger b = new AtomicInteger();
a = 1; b.set(1);
...
// different thread
if (b.get() == 1) // a guaranteed to be 1 here all the time ???
```

If the answer is no, then it should work to extend the AtomicInteger class and include "a" within there, because AtomicInteger wraps a volatile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `get()` is equivalent to reading from a `volatile` variable, and a `set()` is equivalent to writing to it. We have a *happens-before* relationship here write -> read and therefore, "a guaranteed to be 1 here all the time". This of course is in the context of only these two threads executing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. What made me nervous, was the fact that the docs call an AtomicInteger a variable, while it is a separate object. But so it works like a volatile variable. I guess this semantics should cause two different cache lines possibly being affected when accessing. Wrapping "a" into an extended Atomic class might reduce this to one.

Answer (score 1):

If only the documentation would not specify that explicitly:

> Sets the value of a variable to the newValue, with memory semantics of setting **as if the variable was declared volatile**.

If that is the *only* code you have that work on that `AtomicInteger`, then yes, `a` is guaranteed to be `1`.

Answer (score 0):

> a guaranteed to be 1 here all the time ???

No, other `set` calls can happen in between.

But then this is also true in the `volatile` case.